# Finding delete entity calls to Azure storage table

Tags: storage, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

Is there a way to find out if there was any delete entity call to a azure table in last 'N' minutes? Basically my goal is to find all operations that updated the table in last 'N' minutes.

Update: I am looking for a way to do it with a rest api call for a specific table in the storage.

Answer (score 1):

If using Azure Portal an option, you can find this information via `Metrics`. For example, see the screenshot below

[image]]

Basically here I am taking a sum of all transactions against my table storage where API call was `DeleteEntity`.

You can find more information about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-metrics-in-azure-monitor?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json.

**UPDATE**

If you wish to get this information programmatically, I believe you will need to use `Azure Monitoring REST API`. I looked up the request sent by Portal and it is sending a request to `/subscriptions/<my-subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<my-resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<my-storage-account>/tableServices/default/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Transactions` endpoint.

**UPDATE 2**

For a specific table, the only option I can think of is to fetch the data from [`Storage Analytics Logs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging) which is stored in `$logs` blob container and then parse the CSV file manually. You may find these links helpful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-logged-operations-and-status-messages#logged-operations

Comment: Hi, Thanks Gaurav. I am looking to do it from code and rest api call is what I need. Updated the question.

Comment: This one is still on all the tables, I want to limit to a specific table. Can I do so? Basically want to filter on table name type any dimension, any DOC which might explain this?

Comment: Updated my answer again :). HTH.